# assigning a session hash with a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, hash

I'm trying to set the value of a session hash using a method like this:

```
omni = request.env["omniauth.auth"]    
session["devise.user_attributes"] = personal_info(omni)
```

The return value of the method is just a hash:

```
def personal_info(omni)
  facebook_info = omni["extra"]["raw_info"]
  registration_data = {email: facebook_info["email"]}
  registration_data[:gender] = facebook_info["gender"]
  registration_data
end
```

I can call the method directly and get the hash returned, but when I check the value of the session I get an empty hash `{}` and when I check the value of the specific part of the session, `session["devise.user_attributes"]` I get `nil` back. Can anyone explain why this is happening? Is there something I don't understand about storing data in a session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was in how I was trying to verify my session was properly being set. The above code did work ...

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
session.merge! "devise.user_attributes" => personal_info(omni)
```

Comment: That didn't do anything as far as I can tell. Mind explaining what you were trying to do with that?

Comment: I'm trying to merge  the user attributes hash into the session